# Why My Assert Fails? (Exception thrown)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, testing

I'm using testing in my code, and by my understanding, all a test requires to run in a method is this:

```
private ClassName(Argument)
{
    return;
}
```

So what the test is actually checking is if the "Argument" is the correct output at the end of the method/test.

However in my case the argument passed in has nothing to do with the output. Therefore I am uncertain of how to test it.

**NOTE:** The code itself is sound, it outputs the correct variables. Also I actually wrote the test after the code (Big booboo, I know. I want to get into the habit of always testing.)

**EDIT:** I believe the issue is to do with the Test being exited via the `LoginView.Close` and `LoginView.Menu.SetMenuView`. (The function ends on this line, and the test cannot complete?)

The Location of the `return;` also affects the rest of the code, so it needs to be at the end of the code. If I move it up, the rest of the code becomes unreachable, and the program breaks.

I have looked for ways to try and bypass the exceptions, and all I have come up with is to test that the exception is actually being thrown correctly. **Is there a way to bypass the exception in the test?**

Here is the test:

```
public void Compare_LoginTest()
{
    User_LoginView LoginView = new User_LoginView();
    User_Controller.screenName = "ben";
    User_Controller.screenPwd = "password";
    User_Controller.Compare_Login(LoginView);
    int actual = User_Controller.screenAccess;
    int expected = 1;
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Here is the method being tested:

```
    public static  void Compare_Login(User_LoginView LoginView)
    {
        // Creates a new oject of User_Model and populates it from the User_Controller.
        User_Model AccessModel = new User_Model();
        AccessModel.Name = screenName;
        AccessModel.Pwd = screenPwd;

        // Runs the Login Comparsion in the Database_Facade, and passes in the Model.
        Database_Facade Database = new Database_Facade();
        Database.GetLoginAccess(AccessModel);
        screenAccess = AccessModel.AccessLevel;
        Menu_View.accessLevelSet = AccessModel.AccessLevel;

        // Compares the returned AccessLevel. 
        // if it is corect; closes the Login and runs the SetMenuView method,
        // if it is incorrect; shows an error.
        if (AccessModel.AccessLevel > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Access Level " + AccessModel.AccessLevel);
            // Exception Thrown in testing.
            LoginView.Close();
            LoginView.Menu.SetMenuView();
        }
        else
        {
            ErrorCodes_Controller LoginError = new ErrorCodes_Controller();
            LoginError.WrongLoginError();
        }
        return;
    }
```

Comment: You should break that up into smaller functions that do discrete tasks (eg, validate password) & test those.

Comment: Ever heard of regular expressions?

Comment: So what exactly happens? Do you expect people to debug your code in the browser? I see stackoverflow is becoming 'makemyhomeworkforme.com'.

Comment: @Peri I understand what you're saying, but I'm not asking you to solve the problem for me. I'm an amateur with an incredibly steep learning curve, so an understanding of how the testing in Visual Studio works is what I'm asking, and I'm only using my code as a reference.

Comment: So isn't your question 'why my Assert fails"? If not I don't know what it is.

Comment: @Peri that's very true. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you're asking... The test will pass if the static `UserController.screenAccess` variable is 1 - and it looks like the `Compare_Login` method always sets it to 1.

This all looks fine, so if your test is failing, then there's something preventing the code from reaching that point.

For most unit test frameworks (I'm guessing you're just using the built in microsoft one?), exceptions are how unit test methods pass or fail - The `Assert.Xyz` methods throw an exception if the assertion isn't right, otherwise they don't. Any other exceptions that your code may throw also count as a fail.
The test framework catches any exceptions and flags the test as passed if there aren't any

I would guess that something in the `Check_Login` function or earlier in the `Compare_Login` function is throwing an exception. This is the only thing I can see that would cause your unit test to fail. I'm surprised however that you haven't noticed such an exception (try clicking on the failing unit test and seeing what details you can see about the failure)

Comment: the `screenAccess` variable was a bogus variable to see what the test was doing. I also looked through the code and saw that the `LoginView.Close()` and the `LoginView.Menu.SetMenuView()` were both throwing Exceptions (I'm not sure I understand why?) but if a move the `return;` up, the rest of the code becomes unreachable.

Comment: That explains it.  The exceptions are what's causing your test to fail. If you move the `return` up, then the function exits before `LoginView.Close()` runs, so it won't throw it's exception (and therefore the test will pass). Fix the exceptions, and it should be OK.

Why are there exceptions? Who knows. I don't know what kind of framework your libraries you are using

Comment: Ok so the issue is being caused by the test being exited before the `return`? i.e. the `LoginView.Close` and the `LoginView.Menu.SetMenuView` because the argument used is the `LoginView`. But like I said before, if I move the `return` up, the rest of the code becomes unreachable.

Comment: No, the issue is caused by your Close or SetMenuView functions throwing exceptions. I don't think your assert is failing, I think it's probably not even getting that far - As soon as one of those functions throws an exception, the test exits immediately. If you move the `return` up, then these functions never run, so there's no exception - then your assert can check that `screenAccess` is 1, and pass